# How can i get params in spring from curl -X request?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http, curl

I have a problem with processing params from curl request to my spring-boot app.

My controller post method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cat", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity addCat(@Valid @ModelAttribute NewCatRequest newCatRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println( newCatRequest);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
    }

    int rowsAffected = catsRepository.saveCat(newCatRequest.getName(), newCatRequest.getColor(), newCatRequest.getTail_length(), newCatRequest.getWhiskers_length());
    if (rowsAffected == 1) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(newCatRequest);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("There was an unexpected error while trying to create cat for you :(");
    }
}
```

And the problem is: when i'm trying to send this with curl:

> curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/cat \
>   -d "{\"name\": \"Tihon\", \"color\": \"red & white\", \"tail_length\": 15, \"whiskers_length\": 12}"

I have all null params in 'newCatRequest':
NewCatRequest{name='null', color='null', tail_length=0, whiskers_length=0}

BUT when i'm trying to do the same with Postman (POST method, x-www-form-urlencoded in body with my params) i have a valid result:
[Result from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89shl.png)

Help me pls to understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/cat \
     -d "{\"name\": \"Tihon\", \"color\": \"red & white\", \"tail_length\": 15, \"whiskers_length\": 12}"
```

The above `curl` request has a JSON body, whereas your request processing method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cat", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
```

consumes/accepts: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Therefore, you should either convert your method to consume/accept `application/json` or change your `curl` request to:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/cat \
     -d 'name=Tihon&color=red%20%26%20white&tail_length=15&whiskers_length= 12' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

**EDIT 1**

Please note that the default *Content-Type* for **curl** is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To use JSON, change your request to:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/cat \
     -d "{\"name\": \"Tihon\", \"color\": \"red & white\", \"tail_length\": 15, \"whiskers_length\": 12}" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Comment: After changing the MediaType to MediaType.Application_JSON_VALUE my controller said to me that  Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported]. Sended curl this time was the same as in my first question

Comment: And even if i add -H 'Content-Type: application/json' to the curl request and consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in my controller - i have the same problem (null fields NewCatRequest{name='null', color='null', tail_length=0, whiskers_length=0)

Comment: Adding RequestBody after Valid annotation helped me. Also i save the MediaType as application/json/ And the problem with curl request withou specifying the content type in header was because default content-type setted to x-www-form-urlecoded. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code option below send button in postman to generate the exact curl request which will work for you  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbk8M.png
in code drop down menu search for curl and it will generate a neat and clean curl request for you .
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/cat \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'name=Thidon&color=red%20%26%20white&tail_length=15&whiskers_length=12'
```

You forgot the header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`and the body should not be in json format.